# Cross Compile on maxOS fails linking System library (CMake), but other libraries succeed

Tags: c, cross-compilation, software-compilation, macos, gcc

*tl;dr - CMake fails at linker not finding `System` library with precompiled RaspberryPi toolchain when other libraries work*

So I've been fighting this for a few days, and I believe I'm nearing the end of my journey to get an ARM executable for the RaspberryPi compiled through CMake on macOS Sierra.

Currently, I'm using the pre-compiled RaspberryPi toolchain from [this blog](https://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/cross-compiling-on-mac-osx-for-raspberry-pi/), and getting the following results:

```
macbook:gpsexample alex$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Volumes/linuxdev/gpsexample
macbook:gpsexample alex$ make
[ 20%] Linking C executable gpsexample
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [gpsexample] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gpsexample.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've previously had problems linking the `m` library with the same error, however adding the proper system root fixed that issue. I have a feeling I'm missing another library or directory - however I'm not too sure where.

Below is my CMakeLists.txt (single file only):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.2)
project (gpsexample)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/Volumes/xtools/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot")

#Enable POSIX Threading
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pthread")

#Bring the headers in
include_directories(include)

#Wildcard add all source files in dir
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")

#Create the target
add_executable(gpsexample ${SOURCES})

#Link the standard math lib to the exec
target_link_libraries(gpsexample m)
```

Is there somewhere else I should add for a library to get `System` found? Will I need to download the raw files from the Pi directly and include them in the custom tools directory?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?